# is PHP 7.3 is compatible with RHEL 8.3?

Tags: php-7.3, rhel8

As per official documentation of [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 Application Streams Life Cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhel8-app-streams-life-cycle),

PHP 7.4 is available on RHEL 8.3, But I want to check compatibility of PHP 7.3 with RHEL 8.3.
Can someone confirm PHP 7.3 is available on RHEL 8.3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, php7.3 is compatible with RedHat 8.3.

Find the below installation a blog for php7.3 in RHEL 8.3.

```
https://www.techoism.com/how-to-install-php-7-4-7-3-7-2-7-1-on-centos-rhel-8/
```